# Python: creating a range of numbers from a list

Tags: python, list, range, primes

I am new to coding, and I am trying to write a somewhat generic prime number program. The difference with mine is that I want my program to be more efficient and only check numbers equal to, and including the square root of the number being checked, and I only want it to check previously found prime numbers. So far I have accomplished only the first criteria.

```
from numpy import sqrt, ceil
for a in range (3, 10000):
     k=0
     b=ceil(sqrt(a))
     for i in range(2, int(b))
          if (a%i==0):
             k=k+1
     if(k<=0):
         print(a)
```

I think that I need to create a list with the number 2, run the program, and append any prime numbers that are printed to the list. However, I do not know how to:

1.) Make sure only numbers on said list are checked.

2.) Make sure only numbers through sqrt(a) are checked.

Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: You don't need `numpy` for this exercise. `from math import sqrt, ceil` is more than enough.

Comment: You want to remember the primes that have been found, so store them in a list rather than just printing them. You correctly mention appending primes as they are found; to do use `primes.append(new_prime)`. Also, `int(sqrt(a))` is sufficient because `int` will round positive numbers down as needed. Finally, use `break` once you find a factor to skip to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remember the primes that have been found, so store them in a list rather than just printing them. You mention appending primes as they are found; to do use `primes.append(new_prime)`. Use `break` once you find a factor or once you pass the square root to skip to the next iteration.

```
primes = [2]
for tested_number in range(3, 10000, 2): #skip the evens
    is_prime = True # if this is still true after testing, number is prime
    for prime in primes:
        if tested_number%prime == 0:
            is_prime = False
            break
        elif prime>sqrt(tested_number): # no need to check these primes 
            break
    if is_prime:
        primes.append(tested_number)
```